# creating product programatically in magento with table prefix

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I am trying to create product in magento programatically. This script works well with default installation. However it shows below error when I try to create a product in those magento installation where I have given table prefix. Can you please tell me what I need to make changes?

> Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`databasename_magento`.`catalog_category_product_index`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_CTGR_PRD_IDX_CTGR_ID_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_category_entity` (`entity_)

```
$product = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();
$product->setSku($sku);
$product->setAttributeSetId(9);
$product->setTypeId('simple');
$product->setName('55');
$product->setCategoryIds(array(7)); # some cat id's, my is 7
$product->setWebsiteIDs(array(1)); # Website id, my is 1 (default frontend)
$product->setDescription('Gift card Full description here');
$product->setShortDescription('Gift Card Short description here');
$product->setPrice('200'); # Set some price   
$product->setWeight(4.0000);
$product->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE);
$product->setStatus(1);
$product->setTaxClassId(0); # My default tax class
$product->setStockData(array( 'is_in_stock' => 1, 'qty' => 9999 ));

$product->save();
```

Comment: you have another issue $product->setWebsiteIds(array(1));

Answer (score 1):

Error message clearly notifying that the foreign key integrity is violated on `category_id` field.

```
$product->setCategoryIds(array(7)); # some cat id's, my is 7
```

Above statement must be causing an error because the value you are setting is not present in the referred parent column `catalog_category_entity (entity_id)`.

Change the input to be an existing value in parent table and run. And it should be working.

Comment: i have now commented the  setattributeset code and setcategory as well. now it is showing this error An error occurred while saving this configuration: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`magento_prefix`.`nirmesh_catalog_product_entity`, CONSTRAINT `FK_0B09B337C6C1DFD50D7584CD91175F23` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_set_id`) REFERENCES `nirmesh_eav_attribute_set` (`attribute_set_id`))

Comment: I have fixed it myself the issue was obvious Thanks for showing me the correct path.

actually i was setting the attribute set id as 7 which is for "default" in magento installation with dummy data but for simple magento installation it comes as "4". That was the reason of second error.also I have to set the category id which really exist.